# Magento 2 Disable browser scrolling while Minicart (DropdownDialog) is open?

Tags: php, jquery, magento, magento2

In regards to Magento 2, is it possible to disable scrolling in the browser (just for browser's scrollbars) while a Minicart (DropdownDialog) is open?

Screenshot:

[image]

```
        <div class="block block-minicart empty"
         data-role="dropdownDialog"
         data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
            "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
            "triggerTarget":".showcart",
            "timeout": "2000",
            "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
            "closeOnEscape": true,
            "triggerClass":"active",
            "parentClass":"active",
            "buttons":[]}}'>
        <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        </div>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons'); ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To quickly demonstrate, I will work directly with file

```
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js
```

But I do this merely to give you an idea.

The actual implementation that you will do should extend the `minicart.js`, for which I hope you either know how to do it, or, there are enough resources available somewhere else.

Anyways, in the `minicart.js` file there is a code like

```
miniCart.on('dropdowndialogopen', function () {
    initSidebar();
});
```

This executes when the minicart is opened. So, you could edit to something like:

```
miniCart.on('dropdowndialogopen', function () {
    initSidebar();
    $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
});
```

In order to re-enable scrolling when the minicart is closed, right below the code from above, you could add this code

```
miniCart.on('dropdowndialogclose', function () {
    $('body').css('overflow','scroll');
});
```

minicart.js is deployed (by default) on almost all pages, except the checkout I guess. If you make sure your compoment, that will override the minicart.js deploys in the same way, this feature it will work regardless of window size (i.e. tablets and phone views will work as well).

I hope this helps.